# no suitable method found for add(TextField)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a model browser, but this one error keeps coming up from a seemingly fine line of code.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author PC
 */
public class Browser extends JFrame{
    private TextField field = new TextField();
    private JEditorPane display = new JEditorPane();
    private JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(display);

    public static void main(String args[]){
    Browser file = new Browser();
    file.framelander();
    }

    public void framelander() {
       setTitle("Browser");
       setSize(1200, 800);
       setResizable(false);
       setVisible(true);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setLayout(null);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       addComponentsToFrame(getContentPane());
    }

    public void addComponentsToFrame(Container pane) {
        Insets insets = getInsets();

        pane.add(field);
        pane.add(scroller);

        Font font = new Font("Menlo", Font.PLAIN, 11);
    field.setFont(font);
    }



}
```

The error I'm getting is at pane.add(field) with the error;

```
no suitable method found for add(TextField)
    method Component.add(PopupMenu) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; TextField cannot be converted to PopupMenu)
    method Container.add(Component) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; TextField cannot be converted to Component)
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

I'm also getting "incompatible types:java.awt.Font cannot be converted to javafx.scene.text.Font" at the bold part of *field.setFont(**font**);* but I'm assuming that's due to the initial error. I will post it here just in case however.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your hint should be "Cannot be converted" along with the package name ... `javafx` and `awt` classes are not entirely compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're importing the wrong `TextField`.

```
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
```

You probably want to import this one:

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
```

And then change `field` to a `JTextField`

```
private JTextField field = new JTextField();
```

This should fix all of the errors you described.
Also, your JFrame should have a layout set and I advise you to look into this guide [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: `"You probably want to import this one: java.awt.TextField"` --  Nope. Don't encourage mixing of AWT and Swing components if not necessary.

Comment: Other than using JTextField from Swing, I don't see why wouldn't he use that one, based on the context and how he's trying to use it. I just saw the name of the class he was using and went with it, but I get your point.